# Analytic solution for $x=\ln(x+1)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I plotted the graphs of $x$ and $\ln(x+1)$ and found they meet when $x= 0$, is there any way to show this analitically? I tried $e^x = x+1$ but its actually the same

Comment: Just plug in $0$? $x=0$ and $\ln(0+1)=\ln(1)=0$.

Comment: What do you mean "analytical"? $\ln (x+1) = 0$ if and only if $x=0$. This is a basic property of the logarithm.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 I guess the question is how to solve x=ln(x+1).

Comment: You can compare the derivatives to proof that $x=0$ is the only solution.

Comment: Yes Im asking how to solve x=ln(x+1) I know x=0 is a solution how do i prove is the only one

Answer (score 2):

By the integral definition of the natural logarithm,

$$\ln(1+x)=\int_0^x{dt\over1+t}\quad\text{for }x\gt-1$$

Noting that $x=\int_0^xdt$, we have

$$x-\ln(1+x)=\int_0^x\left(1-{1\over1+t}\right)dt=\int_0^x{t\over1+t}\,dt$$

It's obvious that $\int_0^0{t\over1+t}dt=0$.  And since ${t\over1+t}\gt0$ for $t\gt0$ and ${t\over1+t}\lt0$ for $-1\lt t\lt0$, we have $\int_0^x{t\over1+t}dt\gt0$ if $x\not=0$ (and $x\gt-1$).  So $x=0$ is the only solution of $x=\ln(1+x)$.

Remark:  the subtlest point here may be the general implication

$$f(t)\lt0\text{ for }t\lt0 \implies \int_0^xf(t)\,dt\gt0\text{ for }x\lt0$$

Answer (score 1):

Let
$f(x)
=x-\ln(x+1)
$.
$f(0) = 0$,
so that is one root.

$f'(x)
=1-\frac1{x+1}
=\frac{(x+1)-1}{x+1}
=\frac{x}{x+1}
\gt 0
$
for
$x > 0$
and
$f'(x)
< 0$
for
$-1 < x < 0$.

Therefore
$f(x)$
is decreasing for
$-1 < x < 0$
and is increasing for
$0 < x$.

Since
$f(0) = 0$,
$f(x)$ has a unique minimum at
$x=0$
so this is
its only root.

Answer (score 0):

By inspection, one may note $\ln  (0 + 1) = 0$, hence $x=0$  is a solution. This is unique because $\log$ is a strictly convex $C^2$ function, hence its tangent at $x=0$ is strictly above its graph for $x \neq 0$.